# Getting a list of children for a node in Prolog

Tags: search, tree, prolog

I'm trying to do a simple tree search in Prolog, and I need a function that would return a list of children for a given node.

My code is:

```
root(a).
node(a, [b, c]).
node(b, []).
node(c, [d, e, f]).
node(d, []).
node(e, []).
node(f, []).

children(node(_, Kids), Kids).

node_matches(_,_).
node_matches(Criteria, [Head|Tail]) :- node_matches(Criteria, Head), node_matches(Criteria, Tail).

search_node(Criteria, [Node]) :- node_matches(Criteria, Node), search_node(Criteria, children(Node)).
```

Currently I'm getting and error Undefined procedure: children/1, which makes sense, because I haven't implemented a function with 1 argument. 
How can I implement such a function?

Comment: What do you think `node_matches(_,_).` means ?

Comment: Prolog doesn't know what your logic needs to be for defining a rule. So when you define `children(node(_, Kids), Kids).`, then queries such as `children(node(123, foo), foo).` succeed. Also, Prolog doesn't know that the `node/2` inside your `children/2` fact is the same as the `node/2` that you've defined as facts. Finally, you haven't said how you want your predicate to behave. An example would help.

Comment: These are *not* functions, but *predicates*, this is not just nomenclature, but it thus means that `children(whatever)`, can only be `true` or `false` (or raise an error, or get stuck in an infinite loop).

Comment: @CapelliC `node_matches(_,_).` is just a temporary placeholder for a predicate that will later on hold more exact logic for matching. Currently, it just returns true if given 2 equal values.

Comment: @lurker - I want to return the array of children for a current node. I believe it would look like children(a), but I'm not sure whether Prolog works this way - so that's why I'm asking.

Comment: The list of children for a given node `N` is already given by `node(N, Children)`.  So I assume you mean recursively? Your code shows some basic misunderstanding of how Prolog works. So before diving into writing another predicate you shod search this site for more examples and perhaps go through a tutorial.

Comment: I guess I'm not pro enough for prolog.

Comment: no, 'Currently, it just returns true if given 2 equal values.' is incorrect. Instead, 'Currently, it just returns true.'

Comment: @CapelliC True.. I guess the predicate for 2 equal values will look like node_matches(X1 == X2).

Comment: You don't need to be "pro". You just need to get a few basics down.

Comment: The biggest problem with Prolog is knowing how to program in another language and assuming it won't be hard to pick up. The second biggest problem, I'm starting to think, is seeing Prolog as logic programming rather than programming with unification and backtracking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are interested in a list, why not considering the use of DCGs for the task? After all, DCGs describe lists and they yield easily readable code. Conveniently, your given facts node/2 provide the direct successors of a node in a list, so it is opportune to use a list of nodes to be visited as the DCGs single argument. The DCG itself could be named after what it describes, for example children//1. You can define a calling predicate, let's also give it a nice descriptive name, say node_children/2, that uses phrase/2 to call the DCG:

```
node_children(N,C) :-
   node(N,Succs),             % Succs are the direct successors of node N
   phrase(children(Succs),C). % based on them the DCG children//1 describes the list C
```

The DGC children//1 has to describe a list that consists of all the nodes in its argument-list and their respective children, that is, their respective successors, their successors' successors, and so on (that wording already bears the scent of recursion :-). So children//1 might look something like this:

```
children([]) -->       % if there are no nodes
   [].                 % there are no children
children([N|Ns]) -->   % N, the first node in the list...
   {node(N,Succs)},    % ...has the direct successors Succs...
   [N],                % ...and is in the list of children...
   children(Succs),    % ...as well as its successors and their children...
   children(Ns).       % ...as well as the other nodes in the list
```

In the first goal of the recursive rule of children//1, `{node(N,Succs)}`, you can observe how predicates can be called in a DCG, namely enclosed by braces. Now let's see node_children/2 in action:

```
   ?- node_children(a,C).
C = [b,c,d,e,f]
   ?- node_children(b,C).
C = []
   ?- node_children(c,C).
C = [d,e,f]
```

You can also ask more general queries like *What nodes and respective children are there?*:

```
   ?- node_children(N,C).
C = [b,c,d,e,f],
N = a ? ;
C = [],
N = b ? ;
C = [d,e,f],
N = c ? ;
C = [],
N = d ? ;
C = [],
N = e ? ;
C = [],
N = f
```

Or *Which nodes have three children?*:

```
   ?- C=[_,_,_], node_children(N,C).
C = [d,e,f],
N = c ? ;
no
```

Two closing remarks: You can see how the DCG children//1 is translated into a predicate by querying `?- listing(children).`. To learn more about DCGs I can wholeheartedly recommend [this DCG Primer](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/dcg).